# How to add your files across cluster on pyspark AWS

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I am new to spark. I am trying to read a file from my master instance but I am getting this error. After research I found out either you need to load data to hdfs or copy across clusters. I am unable to find the commands for doing either of these.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 ncols = rdd.first().features.size  # number of columns (no class) of the dataset
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in first(self)    1359
>   ValueError: RDD is empty    1360         """
>   -> 1361         rs = self.take(1)    1362         if rs:    1363             return rs[0]
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in take(self, num)    1311
>   """    1312         items = []
>   -> 1313         totalParts = self.getNumPartitions()    1314         partsScanned = 0    1315
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in getNumPartitions(self) 
>   2438     2439     def getNumPartitions(self):
>   -> 2440         return self._prev_jrdd.partitions().size()    2441     2442     @property
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1131         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1132         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1134     1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       320             else:
>       321                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o122.partitions. :
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
>   exist: file:/home/ec2-user/PR_DATA_35.csv     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in AWS already, it may be easier to just store your data files in s3, and open them directly from there.